# "noNegators" option is not working in SentiStrength

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I'm trying out SentiStrength commandline options. "noNegators"(don't use negating words (e.g., not) to flip sentiment) doesn't seem to work fine.

Below is the command given in commandline:
java -jar SentiStrength.jar sentidata C:\conf\PosNeg\ text happy+and+not+satisfied noNegators explain

Output:
3 -2 happy[3]and not satisfied[3][*-0.5 approx. negated multiplier][sentence: 3,
-2] [result: max + and - of any sentence]

Expected: It shouldn't have considered "not"

Please suggest.